# Placing boxes with css

Tags: html, css

I am making a html page and have 3 sort of boxes, i have a 20% width(named single-box) and 40% width called double-box (both have hight 33%).

The other bbox is 100% height( named foto-box), 40% width.

Now i want to float next to eachother: double-box, singel-box, foto-box.
Then i want all single boxes, but the single bbox is getting under the 100% of the foto-box. How can i

```css
html, body{
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #c5c5c5;
}
.screen{
    width: 98%;
    height: 98%;
    margin: 1% 1% 1% 1%;

}
.dubble-box{
    width: 40%;
    height: 33%;
    background-color: aqua;
    float: left;
}
.single-box{
    height: 33%;
    width: 20%;
    background-color: black;
    float: left;
}
.picture-box{
    width:40%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: bisque;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title></title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css"><!--resets css to default-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css"><!--gives css to page-->
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="lb.png" type="image/png">
<body>
<div class="screen">
    <div class="dubble-box">
        <p> levi</p>
    </div>
    <div class="single-box"></div>
    <div class="picture-box"></div>
    <div class="single-box"></div>


</div>

</body>
```

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zA5dJ.png)

Comment: Is display:grid not an option ? this is a typical use case for that kind of layout .